# Neo4j Create a node type dynamically

Tags: neo4j

I saw that is possible to create relationship type dynamically according to reading csv row but when I'm trying to create a node type it says Invalid input '[': expectedd whitespace or label name

sample:

csv

Type   name
Person Gerard
Person Alice

```
using periodic commit load csv from... as row
merge (node:row[1] {name: row[2]})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create nodes with dynamic labels, or relationships with dynamic types supplied by string variables in Cypher.

You'll need to use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) for this instead, specifically the [procedures for creating data](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data).

An example of usage:

```
using periodic commit load csv from... as row
call apoc.create.node([row[1]], {name:row[2]}) yield node
```

Dynamic merges aren't covered yet, unfortunately, just creates.

Comment: To update, APOC does have dynamic MERGE procedures now for both nodes and relationships.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`apoc.merge.node`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.merge/apoc.merge.node/) procedure:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///...' AS row:
CALL apoc.merge.node(
  [row[1]],
  {id: row[2]}
) yield node
return node
```